# Opening a View page with Custom Route on asp.net core

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I'm having problem in opening my View page on my custom Route I'm using Asp.Net Core 3.1

**BrandController**

```
[Area("CormComm")]
    [Route("CorpComm/[controller]/[Action]")]
    public class BrandController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CorpCommDbContext _context;

        public BrandController(CorpCommDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

Here is my file structure
I added a folder called CorpComm in the View folder and drag the Brand folder inside the CorpComm
Then I run the page and go to `https://localhost:44325/CorpComm/Brand/index` it says

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Areas/CormComm/Views/Brand/Index.cshtml
/Areas/CormComm/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

View Page Structure:

[image]

Controller Structure:

[image]

Hi, This is My routing configs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "corpcomm",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: See typo in `Area` attribute. There is `CormComm` and must be `CorpComm` i think.

Comment: Could you add your routing config too? There must be something like this `endpoints.MapControllerRoute("areas", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`

Comment: Hi @SelimYıldız, I added my routijng configs

Comment: @picolino Hi, I updated the typo but has the same error